# How to list Kafka consumer group using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to get Kafka consumer group list with python but I couldn't.

I use to zookeeper python client( kazoo)  but consumer group list empty because this method for old consumer and we are not using old consumer.

How can I get consumer group list with python code?

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh  -bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily list consumer groups with [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python).

Just send a `ListGroupsRequest` to any of the brokers in your cluster.

For example:

```
from kafka import BrokerConnection
from kafka.protocol.admin import *
import socket

bc = BrokerConnection('localhost', 9092, socket.AF_INET)
bc.connect_blocking()

list_groups_request = ListGroupsRequest_v1()

future = bc.send(list_groups_request)
while not future.is_done:
    for resp, f in bc.recv():
        f.success(resp)

for group in future.value.groups:
    print(group)
```

Comment: is it possible to list the consumer groups for a give topic. I am not able to get the topic details for the consumer groups

Answer (score 3):

You may do this just by using [kafka-python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) module.

```
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient
client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092")
for group in client.list_consumer_groups():
    print(group[0])
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted - it is more up-to-date and succinct than the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

[KIP-222](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-222+-+Add+Consumer+Group+operations+to+Admin+API) was recently introduced to enable Java clients to retrieve all consumer groups. Maybe it needs more time to have librdkafka or python client support this. See details in [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/223).

Comment: There's other Python libraries than the Confluent librd based ones, though