# How can I get consumer group list that is associated with topic in kafka-python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I want to get a Kafka consumer group list by topic in kafka-python but I couldn't.  How can I get consumer group list that is associated with topic in python code:

```
from kafka import BrokerConnection
from kafka.protocol.admin import *
import socket
list_groups_request = ListGroupsRequest_v1()
future = bc.send(list_groups_request)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080471/how-to-list-kafka-consumer-group-using-python/52088863  .. .You would have to describe all groups, then filter them for the topic name.

Comment: @cricket_007  I have tried describe the Topic in Command line  but its listing empty topic a,but it was linked with the topic .  

Tried in 2 approaches.   
1. Used the stack overflow link provided by you

2. Used in this way
Import Kafka

admin_client = Kafka.KafkaAdminClient()
print(admin_client.list_consumer_groups())

For the above line, output is like [‘test-consumer-group’, ‘consumer’]


Now tried to describe it in the following way.

>>> admin_client.describe_consumer_groups(['test-consumer-group'])
[(0, 'test-consumer-group', 'Empty', 'consumer', '', [])]

Comment: The `list_consumer_group_offsets` method will return TopicPartitions for a given group https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets